# Doctrine2 thinks entity is modified when DateTime column is cloned

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine

I'm performing DateTime calculations based on an Entity's `$dateStart` and `$dateEnd`. In order to prevent the changes to be persisted to the database, I clone them in a separate variable:

```
$dateStart = clone $entity->getDateStart();
```

All calculations are fine, but my `EntitySubscriber` does keep on performing `postFlush` events for the entity. It is no option to implement a `__clone()` function for the DateTime object in the entity right?

The [Doctrine cookbook article](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html) on wakeup/clone does not help me with that. Why are the events triggered?

Comment: What about just creating new DateTime object like `$clonedDateTime = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp($entity->getTimestamp())`?  It's a dirty thing, but probably may fix your problem.

Comment: In order to do `$entity->getTimestamp()` i'll first need to get the timestamp itself, so it'll be `$entity->getDateStart()->getTimestamp()`. I think the `->getDateStart()` marks the entity as dirty (?)

Comment: I've tested your solution @RomaKliuchko, but unfortunately it does not work.